# Issue pushing to detail view when tabBarController/navController in same app

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am having some difficulty getting a `tableView` to push to a detail view with  `self.navigationController` and `pushViewController`.

I have determined that my problem comes from my appdelegate.m file. My app first loads a single window, then loads a tab bar controller. now I am trying to introduce the navigation controller on the page I need it. I am trying to merge two different projects together.

Any help would be great!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    PDCWelcomeViewController *welcomeVC = [[PDCWelcomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PDCWelcomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.slideUpNav = [[PDCSlideUpNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:welcomeVC];
    self.slideUpNav.navigationBarHidden = isUserLoggedIn;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.slideUpNav;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;



    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [self.viewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor underPageBackgroundColor]];
    UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navControl;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Your method returns twice, is that normal ? Xcode doesn't warn you about dead code ?

Comment: This code make no sense.

Comment: no definitely not normal, i don't get a warning about it. I almost have two different apps running at the same time. When I comment out everything after the first "return YES" the app pushes the navcontroller like I want, but I lose the tab bar. When I remove everything after the first "return YES", the app has the tab bar, but I lose the navigation capability. I am trying to combine the two.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of both the apps

Answer (score 1):

It can only load `PDCWelcomeViewController`. After its there is a return statement. So below that statement, the code is of no worth.